# How to do this in regex in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

Format of string is any of the following... language is ruby

```
#word > subcategory
#word word > sub / category
#word > sub category
#word word > subcategory
```

I just want to match the "word" or "word word" (two words with a space)

So far I have this but its not matching the space

```
scan(/#([^ ]*)/)[0]
```

Also, for the second one it appears to be working however certain phrases arent matching even though they're identical. I have no idea why. Is there something wrong with the following? (this is to match "subcategory" or "sub category"

```
scan(/.* > (.*)$/)[0]
```

The first portion is letters only, the second portion can have any number of spaces, words, characters like / or _

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question.

Do you want to retrive XXX and YYY in the form of "#XXX > YYY"?

In that case, following regular expression will help:

```
scan(/#([^>]*?) *> *(.*)$/)
```

For example:

```
> "#world world > sub / category".scan(/#([^>]*?) *> *(.*)$/)
=> [["world world", "sub / category"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
^#([^>]*)
```

`[^>]*` will match anything until the first `>` (or the end of the text).
`^` is not really needed, but it may protect you from mistakes (for example, if the category contains another hash sign)

Working example: http://rubular.com/r/LO6T9AV3rp

Note that you can match both the word and the category on the same match, for example, using the pattern:

```
^#([^>]*)>(.*)$
```

You can capture both groups, and use them:

```
s = "#word word > sub / category"
m = s.scan(/^#([^>]*)>(.*)$/)
puts m[0]
puts m[1]
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/SPlvm

Comment: Thanks mang. How would I exclude the space on the end? right before the >

Comment: @Tallboy - You should go with cinsk's answer in that case. I'm too slow `:)`